# PHP builtin server + SSL

Tags: php

I know that PHP built-in server does not support SSL. Is it achievable anyway?

I tried to use Nginx proxy and proxy_pass all HTTPS requests to `http://127.0.0.1:8080` but when I have a redirect from `http://127.0.0.1:8080` to `https://127.0.0.1:8080` it causes a redirection loop.

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  127.0.0.1;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location / {
      proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

How do you solve that issue?

Comment: That should certainly be possible, since the PHP part isn't doing any SSL at all. Where is the `https://127.0.0.1:8080` redirect coming from, though?

Comment: @halfer A Symfony based application is forcing HTTPS for some URLs. So, the proxy_pass request is being redirected to https which is being redirected to http://127.0.0.1:8080 and so on.

Comment: Right, so dig into the app and manually rewrite the localhost address to the IP/domain of the app on the proxy side. I've not used Symfony2, but there must be a way to do this. Would you add the code to your question that does this?

Comment: @halfer the IP remains the same - I host the stuff on the localhost. About pasting code... I think it's quite impossible - to much code to paste :)

Comment: Right, I think I am not with you. Is Symfony redirecting to `http://localhost`, or `https://localhost`? If it is the latter, then it should be served by the NginX proxy, and if it is the former (no SSL) then Symfony just needs to be configured to swap `http:` with `https:`, and swap the port 8080 to 443 (or remove it) when it does a fully-qualified redirection.

Comment: (Yes, you can't paste the whole app here, but I imagine there is a central place you configure the root domain in the app, either at a framework or app level?)

Comment: (Aside: it might be worth configuring this on your local machine so that, from your browser, the proxy destination (`http://127.0.0.1:8080`) cannot be seen from your browser. You want to make sure there are no cheeky redirects involving this that it relies on - they won't (or should not be) available in a live environment.)

Comment: @halfer In SF world you are not setting up the domain name, it's being taken from the server configuration.

Proxy destination is visible in my browser - I'm developing on my localhost I have my browser installed on.

Comment: "it's being taken from the server configuration" - so you might have to override that then, at the application level.

Comment: If your app is running `http` only then it should not concern itself of redirecting a request to https. So you issue is with the app rather than nginx config. Check why app is doing that

Comment: Question is, WHY on earth do you want to use the PHP built-in server for production? It is single threaded and has terrible performance + its not hardened for production.

Comment: Do not forget to use option "export certdata": proxy_set_header X-SSL-CERT $ssl_client_cert. Only in this way is certificate available to client app for reading etc...

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your `nginx` try the following:

```
upstream local8080 {
  server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}
## HTTP CONFIG
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 127.0.0.1;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

## SSL SERVER
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name 127.0.0.1;
  # Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites, recommended 2048 bits
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

  # modern configuration. tweak to your needs.
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1;
  ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  # OCSP Stapling ---
  # fetch OCSP records from URL in ssl_certificate and cache them
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;

  resolver 127.0.0.1;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/localhost.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private/localhost.key;

location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass https://local8080;
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

I use the above config in my local servers, so it should work. With that said, you need to ensure that `SELinux` is disabled, and `FirewallD` is allowing port 8080.  By default, both will be enabled on a default Linux flavored install, so you must make changes.

You can place SSL certificates in any location, then point to them.

If you're trying to access from an external network, you'll need to allow port 8080 on your router.

If you need help with either `SELinux` or `FirewallD`, just let me know.  I'll get you the code.  If this is a local test environment, then just disable them until you get `nginx` running correctly.

Comment: No, you're referencing the upstream, not the actual URI.  Notice the first line where you see `upstream local8080`.  The upstream can be any name you please.  Call it `localProxy`, or the name of the proxy server `localDev0`.  Then reference it with the upstream name.

Answer (score 1):

Well part of the problem is the way you are using proxy pass, I think.

As far as I can tell you are only listening on port 443, so I don't even think it would accept a port 80 connection in order for the proxy pass to happen.

Secondly, I have never seen proxy pass used for redirecting http to https, but I am also not 100% seasoned at nginx or apache, but I would typically use proxy pass for reverse proxying we requests to subdomains and other directories to various IPs.

Does this post help at all? The answer has a configuration in it:

[nginx force ssl http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127761/nginx-force-ssl-http)

Let me know what you find out, I might have time to test this a bit later, but if you are only listening on port 443 and have it set up to only accept ssl, then an http request would simply fail saying server not reachable.

If you do actually want to have them be able to hit http, but to be forced over to an SSL connection I do not know if proxy pass is the correct way to do that.

Edit:

https://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom

This looks correct

Comment: Proxy pass, imo is more for say, you have your main domain at, domain.com. You can use proxy pass to take a request for subdomain.domain.com and deliver it to a different IP, or a specific web directory on the server etc.

Answer (score 1):

Proxy doesn't help you much, because Symfony doesn't know a protocol and still try to redirect to https.

Try this configuration

```
server {


    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  127.0.0.1;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location / {
        proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect      http://localhost:8080 https://127.0.0.1;

        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```